# How to set font-size of angular material 2 floating labels (using theming or typography)?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have the need to style the Angular (5) Material 2 **floating labels** on input fields.

So for now I am using:

```
.mat-form-field-should-float .mat-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

And it works.

However it seems way better to me to use existing mix-ins, typography or theming, but I can't find any solution for this.

Normal typography theming looks like this:

```
$general-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family:   'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
   ...
  // Line-height must be unit-less fraction of the font-size.
  $input:                        mat-typography-level(17px, 1.125, 400)
);
```

Is there a way, supported by theming, to style (set font-size) of **floating labels / placeholders** ?

Comment: [If I have a look](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/426f11fb13420f96fa0ea49b936dc1975c9172c2/src/lib/core/typography/_all-typography.scss#L41) at the components we **are** able to override, I would guess custom styling of placeholders/labels is not available yet via theming.

Comment: How would you do this overriding? Do you have an example?

Comment: Sure, there is an example [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#customization)